# How do you make a popup menu appear when you click on a profile picture in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am currently working on an app and in the main menu there is a small profile picture on the top right side of the screen. I want to make that pfp clickable and when the user clicks on it, it should display a popup menu to show some extra things such as, view profile, settings, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this for an [AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html):

```
await showDialog
```

Or this if you want it as a [Bottom sheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) :

```
await showModalBottomSheet...
```